# Leverage browser caching in modx?

Tags: php, .htaccess, modx

I'm extremely new to modx but have "leveraged the browser cache" many times for other cms's/static pages.

I've added this:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

To the .htaccess in the public_html folder like I do to most of my sites and google is saying it's not working. I also went into the cms itself and found the ht.access file and dropped in there (it was different than in the ftp). Still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the response headers in the browser dev tools on the network tab. And see if the date is set for 1 year for an image. Also you need to make sure mod_expires is enabled on the server.

Comment: @PanamaJack
This is all I get in the response headers for an image:

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified


Server: nginx/1.6.2


Date: Thu, 19 Mar 2015 12:35:03 GMT


Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Feb 2013 21:11:39 GMT


Connection: keep-alive


ETag: "512e768b-239a6"



Does it make a difference that it's nginx?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're using nginx and not Apache.

See [Leverage browser caching for Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/leverage-browser-caching-for-nginx)